# Dynamically alter urls.py to support dynamically created URLs?

Tags: django

I'd like to create a web service using Django that dynamically adds URLs to my urls.py file. Can this be done in Django? In other words, I'd like to have users be able to sign up for an end point that gets dynamically created using Django, e.g. my domain "dynamicurl.com" could add /johnp/ via a registration of user johnp. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a pattern that matches the required characters for your username. Here is an example:

```
url(r'(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$',
    'yourapp.views.user_home', name='user-home'),
```

Then, when someone goes to `yourdomain.com/johnp/` in your view you can do something like:

```
def user_home(request, username=None):
    return render(request, 'user_home.html', {'username': username})
```

In `user_home.html`:

```
<strong>Welcome {{ username }}</strong>
```

Which will result in:

**Welcome johnp**

Answer (score 1):

Consider this situation.

Suppose at some point in time you have a million users, your urls.py file will have a million records for user pages only. And I hope you do not wish to have separate views to handle all these separate urls.

Therefore, it is better define url patterns that can dynamically alter the content inside the templates depending on the value received within the url.

Using class based views, this can be done as follows:

In your urls.py file, write

```
url(r'^(?P<user_name>(.*))/$',ProfileView.as_view(),name='profile-view'),

class ProfileView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "abc.html"

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_name'] = kwargs['user_name']
        return context
```

Then, in your template you can use it as `{{user_name}}`.